# Is it possible to host multiple services on a single WCF Service website?

Tags: c#, wcf

We've decided to split functionality of our WCF service in two. The reason is that some of the operations might need minor changes in the future (without breaking existing clients) and if there is a chance of a client calling the service by the time the changes occur we want the client to show that it can contact the server but part of the functionality is temporary unavailable.

Anyhow, the question is, is it possible to host multiple WCF services on a single WCF Service website template project and if so how can you declare them in the .svc file of the website?

Comment: Silly question on a second thought. I think the answer is by having multiple .svc files on the website?

Comment: That's correct. You can even merge different projects' deploys if you watch out for overlapping stuff.